# How can I remove all rows with larger DTLrowi than 10?

Tags: datatool

I constantly receive an updated file (`year.csv`) which should be sorted as shown below.
But only the first 10 rows (after sorting) should be shown.

The MWE works and I can omit all rows with `DTLrowi` larger than 10, but the rows are still there.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{year.csv}
1984|1
1998|1
1999|2
2001|2
2002|2
2003|1
2004|2
2005|20
2006|42
2007|64
2008|90
2009|122
2010|130
2011|149
2012|164
2013|123
2014|184
2015|216
2016|204
2017|185
2018|219
2019|190
2020|25
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={year,quantity}]{year}{year.csv}
\DTLsort{quantity=descending}{year}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Year & Quantity
\DTLforeach*{year}
{\year=year,%
 \quantity=quantity}
{
\\\ifnum\value{DTLrowi}>10
\DTLremovecurrentrow % <<<< ?!?!?!??!!? error
\else
\year & \quantity\fi
}
\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

Adding `\DTLremovecurrentrow` as conditional leads to an error and the log says

> ! Package datatool Error: \DTLreplaceentryforrow can't be used inside \DTLforeach*.

But in the documentation page 75 it says

> The following commands may be used in the body of the \DTLforeach loop,3 to edit the current row of the loop.

Comment: If you have to create reports on time series or other varying datasets on a regular basis i suggest you to look into the combination of R -> knitr -> Latex. Datamanipulation with latex is not funny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to remove rows when you're making a table: the removal would be local and wouldn't affect the data base. Just ignore those rows.

Also you cannot end a conditional in a different cell than it started in, so you need to remove the conditional before issuing `\\`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{year.csv}
1984|1
1998|1
1999|2
2001|2
2002|2
2003|1
2004|2
2005|20
2006|42
2007|64
2008|90
2009|122
2010|130
2011|149
2012|164
2013|123
2014|184
2015|216
2016|204
2017|185
2018|219
2019|190
2020|25
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{|}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={year,quantity}]{year}{year.csv}
\DTLsort{quantity=descending}{year}

\makeatletter
\let\gobble\@gobble
\let\firstofone\@firstofone
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Year & Quantity
\DTLforeach*{year}{\year=year,\quantity=quantity}{%
  \ifnum\value{DTLrowi}>10
    \expandafter\gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\firstofone
  \fi
  {\\ \year & \quantity}%
}
\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect answer for the question!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in a comment, this is fairly simple with if you know something about `R` and `knitr`:

[image: mwe]

File **`test.Rnw`**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
<<table, echo=F,results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
df <- read.csv("year.csv")
print(xtable(head(df,10)),include.rownames=F,booktabs=T)
@
\end{document}
```

File **year.csv**:

```
Year, Quantity
1984, 1
1998, 1
1999, 2
2001, 2
2002, 2
2003, 1
2004, 2
2005, 20
2006, 42
2007, 64
2008, 90
2009, 122
2010, 130
2011, 149
2012, 164
2013, 123
2014, 184
2015, 216
2016, 204
2017, 185
2018, 219
2019, 190
2020, 25
```

Answer (score 2):

`pgfplotstable` has this built in. You can use e.g.

```
row predicate/.code={\ifnum#1>9\relax
  \pgfplotstableuserowfalse
\fi
```

In addition, you have access to the full pgf machinery for defining more complex selection mechanisms. Also, I think you are loading `booktabs` for a reason. One can add its rules e.g. with

```
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule}, 
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}]\loadedtable
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{year.csv}
1984&1
1998&1
1999&2
2001&2
2002&2
2003&1
2004&2
2005&20
2006&42
2007&64
2008&90
2009&122
2010&130
2011&149
2012&164
2013&123
2014&184
2015&216
2016&204
2017&185
2018&219
2019&190
2020&25
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&,header=false]{year.csv}\loadedtable
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,set thousands separator={}}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[display columns/0/.style={column name=Year},
display columns/1/.style={column name=Quantity,column type=l},
sort=true,sort key={[index]1},sort cmp=int >,
row predicate/.code={\ifnum#1>9\relax
  \pgfplotstableuserowfalse
\fi},
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule}, 
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}]\loadedtable
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. This solution suits very well to my document since I already use pgf for plots!

Comment: I end up with `! Package pgfplots Error: The requested list entry with index 1 of \loadedtable
 is too large; this list has not enough elements..` Is there a quick solution or should I upon another question?

Comment: @LukasCB I guess you have still the old data file on your machine. Notice that I changed `|` to `&` and if you just run this code, the `year.csv` won't be overwritten. Either remove it by hand or use `\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{year.csv}`. BTW, it is probably possible to make this work with `|` but this is more of a hack, and you already have one "hacky" answer.... ;-)

Comment: is there a reason why `&` is needed as separation character?

Comment: realised: `filecontents` can not do `tab` as separator!

Comment: @LukasCB I think out of the box `pgfplotstable` only supports `col sep=space|tab|comma|semicolon|colon|braces|&|ampersand` where ironically `|` here separate the options. In this case a simple space would do.